# Apply a loop in JS between X and XX

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

So I have been trying to think of how to explain this in a way that makes sense, but I will show you below, as it makes more sense.

I have this code that works fine but I want to shorten it down into a for each loop or something.

```
$('.holder1').on({
    click: function(){
    $('.box1').css({display: 'none'});
    $('.text1').css({display: 'block'});
    }
});

$('.holder2').on({
    click: function(){
    $('.box2').css({display: 'none'});
    $('.text2').css({display: 'block'});
    }
});

$('.holder3').on({
    click: function(){
    $('.box3').css({display: 'none'});
    $('.text3').css({display: 'block'});
    }
});
```

I have this going on up to 40+, and obviously this code is horrific.

Comment: show some html, that will help to provide good answer

Comment: You should consider adding a general class to all of them, so you only have one selector. If possible.

Comment: Agree with @gowri, your markup is important, please post it.

Answer (score 4):

You can refactor the HTML code to use a common class and `data` attributes. Something like this:

```
<div class="holder" data-box="box1" data-text="text1"></div>
<div class="holder" data-box="box2" data-text="text2"></div>
<div class="holder" data-box="box3" data-text="text3"></div>
```

Then you can have a single click handler for all classes:

```
$('.holder').on({
    click: function(){
        $('.' + $(this).data('box')).css({ display: 'none' });
        $('.' + $(this).data('text')).css({ display: 'block' });
    }
});
```

This avoids the needs for ugly loops to add multiple handlers and iterative `id` attributes, which always turns in to a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem it is possible to iterate over `holder` elements using jQuery `Attribute Starts With` selector ([API docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)):

```
$.each('[class^="holder"]', function(index, item) {
    $(item).on('click', function() {
        $('.box' + index).css({display: 'none'});
        $('.text' + index).css({display: 'block'});
    });
});
```

I would prefer using some common class, though, as Rory McCrossan pointed out in his answer.

Comment: +1 I missed to give a jQuery version of looping.  I like this

Comment: Sick marmelade, sir. Never seen a such beautiful way to do that. what does the "^" stand for after "class"?

Comment: @briosheje `^` selector means, All elements with a title attribute value starting with "holder"

Comment: @briosheje [name^="value"]  selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with the given string.. read on at... http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: The caveat to this approach is if the `index` is not sequential.

Comment: yes, it is assumed, that blocks are ordered, otherwise it might be needed to extract current `index` manually

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i< 40; i++) {
 $('.holder' + i ).on({
    click: function(){
    $('.box' + i).css({display: 'none'});
    $('.text' + i).css({display: 'block'});
    }
 });
}
```

or just add a common class and use it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
     use class .box and .text instead

```
  var holder = $(".holder1");
  for (var i = 2; i<= 40; i++) {
      holder.add($(".holder"+i));
 }
  $(holder).on(
   'click', function(){
    $('.box').css({display: 'none'});
    $('.text').css({display: 'block'});
   }
  });
```

Comment: The problem is `.box` and `.text1` change in each handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("*[class^='holder']").on({
    click: function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("class").replace("holder","");
        $('.box'+id).css({display: 'none'});
        $('.text'+id).css({display: 'block'});
    }
});
```

Comment: `I have this going on up to 40+`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming holders and boxes sit in their respective containers, like

```
<div>
    <div class="holder">a</div>
    <div class="holder">b</div>
    <div class="holder">c</div>
    <div class="holder">d</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="box">a</div>
    <div class="box">b</div>
    <div class="box">c</div>
    <div class="box">d</div>
</div>
```

you can get rid of box/text numbers altogether:

```
    $(".holder").click(function() {
        var n = $(this).index();
        $(".box").eq(n).show();
    });
```

This way it will be much easier to add new elements or change their order.